# Режем строку, сохраняя разделители

Tags: java, строки

Как можно строку формата: `"-99/9"` разбить на массив подстрок `{"-","99","/","9"}`?

Comment: А строка `"--9//9-/9/-9-/-/9 9,9.9;9_9"` как должна быть разбита?

Comment: Никак, это для калькулятора. В нем должно быть два числа.
При чем одно-два числа могут быть отрицательными

Comment: Это я к тому, что задача требует уточнений. Как насчёт вполне корректных операций `1++2`, `3--4`, `5*-6`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Контроль ввода присутствует. Единственное, что может быть- это 
3--4 или -3--4(при разнице между отриц. числами). В любом случае нужно порезать строку и поместить числа и арифм.знаки в отдельные ячейки

Comment: @NickVolynkin♦если калькулятор, то наверное два знака быть не могут, он последний как действие возьмет. Может в таком направлении - https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/4

Comment: @splash58 умножить на отрицательное число - вполне обычная операция для калькулятора.

Comment: я тока что попробовал, калькулятор вычел :)

Comment: @VladislavSolopov вернее вот так https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/7

Comment: @splash58 это баг калькулятора. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Принцип расчета такой: Если в строке 1 знак- значит операция идет с двумя положит числами, 2 знака- с одним отрицательным, 3- в двумя отрицательными. 
На каждый метод решения- у меня будет свой алгоритм решения. 
Но для начала мне нужно разделить полученную строку и узнать кол-во знаков

Comment: Вопрос остался открытым

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем усложнять? Есть числа и что-то между ними. Выделяем числа с двух сторон пробелами, нормализуем строку, чтобы после разбиения не появилось пустых элементов и готово.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2+2*24-78";
        str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+)"," $1 ");
        str = str.trim();
        String[] stack = str.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stack));
    }
}
```

В вопросе ничего не говорилось про десятичный разделитель, функции и скобки.

Правильным подходом по решению задачи это не сразу разбивать строку на отдельные лексемы, а считывая ее последовательно обрабатывать конечным автоматом. За основу можно взять алгоритм из статьи про [обратную польскую нотацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Comment: Mitrofano Что означает "$1" в параметре replaceAll()?

Comment: Это альтернативный доступ к группе. Набор заклинаний ограниченный скобками в регулярном выражении называется группой. Возьмем пример `(reg1)(reg2)`. Если вы работаете через Matcher, то m.group(1) -> reg1, m.group(2) -> reg2. При работе со строками можно использовать альтернативную запись для найденных групп $1, $2, если найденное значение нужно использовать для замены. Посмотрите пример из этой статьи http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Если не известен заранее формат строки или он может изменяться, то я бы предложил следующий алгоритм.

1. Берем длинну строки
2. Создаем пустой список для заполнения
3. Циклом проходим по символам. Выбираем символ и смотрим числовой он или нет (Приводим символ к числу, потом к строке и проверяем на совпадение). Если числовой то смотрим на последний элемент списка и если там тоже число, то модифицируем дописыванием в конец строки последнего списка.

Comment: Вы говорите про обратную польскую запись? Разве в джаве есть списки? Или вы про арэйЛист?

Comment: @VladislavSolopov, так это абстрактно. Хоть HashMap бери, хоть ArrayList. Куда удобнее туда и складывай. В HashMap можно складывать флаг/значение.

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку - регуляркой. Или что-то упускаю? Получится что-то вроде такого:

(regex) `/^(-|+)?(\d+)(\/)(\d+)$/`