# Разделить строку

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, подходящее регулярное выражение на **java**, чтобы разделить строку, содержащую арифметическое выражение, на числа (double) и операции.
Например, после перобразования строки *"15.21*6.3"* должен получиться массив из трех значений *"15.21"*, *"*"* и *"6.3"*.
Пример, работающий для integer-а:

```
String input = "4+7";
String[] split = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)))");
```

Результат:

```
split[0] = "4";
split[1] = "+"; 
split[2]="7";
```

Получить что-то похожее для double пока не удалось.
Спасибо

Comment: По-моему, будет проще просто проходить по строке и искать знаки операций, а всё что между ними принимать за числа.

Comment: Возможно Вы правы. Но тогда сильно усложняются методы обработки вырезанных из строки значений в дальнейшем. Собственно по этой причине и пытаюсь regex-ом получить.

Comment: Почему же сильно усложняются? Я понаписал множество парсеров разных языков на разных языках, всё хорошо получается :) Хотите пример?

Comment: и сейчас появится какой-нибудь классический LR парсер...

Comment: Буду благодарен

Comment: Поиск? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514535/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/514649#514649

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет. В моем случае получилось со следующим вариантом регулярного выражения:

```
String input1 = "48.50+50.20";
String input2 = "48.50*50.20";
String input3 = "48.50-50.20";
String input4 = "48.50/50.20";

String[] splitted = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=(\\+|\\-|\\*|/))|(?<=(\\+|\\-|\\*|/))(?=\\d)");
```

Comment: `(?<=\\d)(?=[-+*/])|(?<=[-+*/])(?=\\d)` так регулярное выражение выглядит более естественно, рекомендую упростить выражение в ответе, так оно эффективнее кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 1):

На Java не пишу, но вряд ли Вам будет трудно перевести из Си-подобного псевдокода.

```
void processLine(string line) {
    // список для чисел
    List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
    // список для символов операций между ними
    List<char> signs = new List<char>();
    string temp = "";
    char t;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length(); i++) {
        t = line[i];
        switch (t) {
            // если знак операции
            case '+': case '-':
            case '*': case '/': {
                if (temp == "") {
                    // ошибка, такого быть не должно
                }
                // обработать прошлую последовательность
                //   символов как число
                numbers.Add((double)temp);
                // очистить сохранённую последовательность
                temp = "";
                // и добавить сам знак
                signs.Add(t);
            } break;
            default: {
                // сохранить знак числа
                temp = temp + t;
            }
        }
    }
    // после последнего знака у нас должно быть
    //     есть ещё одно число
    if (temp == "") {
        // тоже ошибка
    }
    numbers.Add((double)temp);

    //TODO: списки чисел и операций между ними получены,
    //      обрабатывайте на здоровье

    // обратите внимание, что количество элементов в
    // numbers = кол-во эл-в в signs + 1
}
```

Comment: Перевести - не проблема. Спасибо большое за вариант. Попробую прикрутить что-то похожее, если с регулярками не получится. Единственный аргумент, почему пытаюсь - две строчки кода против отдельного метода. Еще раз спасибо